# openssl_public_encrypt(): key type not supported in this PHP build

Tags: php, openssl

I saw tons of ques look like mine, kind of sure its not the same question.

**enviorment**: PHP Version 7.1.33-15+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, openssl-1.1.1g

I want to use sm2 curve to encrypt data, and public\private key both generated by openssl， command：

```
./openssl ecparam -genkey -name SM2 -out priv.key
./openssl ec -in priv.key -pubout -out pub.key
```

and then i try it on php:

```
$pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_public('-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoEcz1UBgi0DQgAE6ULQ5Zxk6rePcMERuONCk0L9R7Bz
GdTTsqAxtEYSQAspJZu5wurPz8sq79WW7ELnjZaXi5o/x8NJ1NabCOoEgg==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----');

openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encrypted_data, $pubKey, $padding=OPENSSL_NO_PADDING);
```

it's fine when i get a $pubKey, and error when encrypt:

> openssl_public_encrypt(): key type not supported in this PHP build!

and no other erorrs, why php can't read sm2 pubKey? (available curves include sm2 for sure). thank for give me any answer or link if you're experienced some error like me, and free to ask if you need to know more information.